# Convergence of exponential of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ be a square matrix. Is the exponential $e^A$ of $A$ is always converging?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Do you know what a matrix norm is?  For instance, have you seen a definition such as 
$$
\|A\|_2 = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|?
$$

Comment: Yes, I know various matrix norms. Ca you please elaborate why the answer should be yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define
$$
e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}A^k
$$
We wish to show that the sequence of partial sums $S_N = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac 1{k!}A^k$ converges to $S = e^A$.  To that end, note that for the (sub-multiplicative) matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ of your choosing, we have
$$
\|S - S_N\| = \left\|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac 1{k!}A^k\right\| \leq \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac 1{k!}\|A^k\| \leq \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac 1{k!}\|A\|^k
$$
The bound on the right approaches zero since the sum $\sum \frac 1{k!}\|A\|^k$ converges (to $e^{\|A\|}$, in fact).