# Solution to the linear system $\dot u = Ju$ when $J$ has complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

Consider the linear system

$$\frac{du}{dt}=Ju, \qquad u(0) = u_0$$

where $J \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ has a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues $a \pm i b$ and initial condition $u_0 \in \mathbb R^2$. I want to show that the solution obtained via the matrix exponential is real.

---

Suppose $J$ is diagonalizable, i.e., $J = T \Lambda T^{-1},$ then
we have

$$u(t)=e^{Jt}u_0 = T e^{\Lambda t} T^{-1}u_0 = T \begin{bmatrix} 
e^{(a+bi)t} & 0 \\
0 & e^{(a-bi)t}
\end{bmatrix} T^{-1}u_0 = e^{at}T \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(bt)+i\sin(bt) & 0 \\
0 & \cos(bt)-i\sin(bt)
\end{bmatrix} T^{-1}u_0 = e^{at}(\cos(bt)TIT^{-1}u_0 + \sin(bt)iT \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} T^{-1}u_0) = e^{at} (\cos(bt)u_0 + \sin(bt) iT \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}T^{-1}u_0)$$

$u_0, \cos(bt), \sin(bt), e^{at}$ are all reals, therefore, we want to show that $iT \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}T^{-1}$ is real. But I'm not quite sure how to do that...

Comment: Please let me know if you agree with my edits.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get that $u(t)$ is real following your procedure. Nonetheless, if $J \in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ (otherwise, no chance that you will have $u(t) \in \mathbb R^2$), you can write the series expansion of $\exp(Jt)$ and obtain
$$
u(t) = e^{Jt}u_0 = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{J^kt^k}{k!}\right) u_0.
$$
The series is guaranteed to converge in the space of matrices with real coefficients (see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350467/convergence-of-exponential-of-a-matrix)) for all $t > 0$. Therefore, $u(t)$ is real.

**Addendum**: you should have a look [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d0dd/69c6ee746938460d49ef099f832d5b6c61ef.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Two facts that will lead to the solution (after some computations):

1) Since you have a complex pair of eigenvalues, both of them are simple (only have one eigenvector) and the respective eigenvectors are also conjugate to each other.

2) $T$ is composed by eigenvectors as columns.